# Get elevation/altitude/floor from a place

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I try to get all the establishments that are inside a mall, I have managed to do it with the following url:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
        sb.append("&radius=700");
        sb.append("&types=" +"store");
        sb.append("&sensor=true");
        sb.append("&key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key));
```

I get the information provided by Google and I convert it into a marker.
The problem is that malls usually have more than one floor and the code does not give me information about its elevation / altitude or the floor to which it belongs.

Is there any way to achieve my purpose?

**UPDATE:** 
I work with shopping centers that Google shows me (they use indoormaps)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use Google Places API you can try using `floor` information provided after geocoding the location. Try looking at this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types)

I hope this helps

Comment: I have tried it but it has not given me any information regarding the floor or altitude

Answer (score 0):

Use the Elevation API to make [elevation requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro#ElevationRequests) which returns a [response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro#ElevationResponses) in meters:

```
"results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 1608.637939453125,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 39.73915360,
            "lng" : -104.98470340
         },
         "resolution" : 4.771975994110107
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
```